# what's TransactionID and RowID and Roll Point size in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm reading a MySQL internal book, but it use InnoDB 3.23.49 as example, and I'm currently use MySQL 5.6 and find that it's inconsistent with the book.How can I get the size of TransactionID and RowID and Roll Point?